# Android Room not updating records properly when tables are joined

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room

I've a `DAO` with following query methods:

```
@Dao
public interface QuoteDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM quotes")
    LiveData<List<Quote>> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM quotes " +
            "INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = quotes.category_id " +
            "WHERE categories.selected = 1")
    LiveData<List<Quote>> getPreferred();

    @Update
    public void update(Quote quote);

}
```

And `Repository` has following methods:

```
public class QuoteRepository {
    private static final String TAG = "Repo/Quote";

    private final QuoteDao quoteDao;
    private LiveData<List<Quote>> quotes;

    private final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public QuoteRepository(Application application){
        quoteDao = DB.getInstance(application).quoteDao();
        quotes = Transformations.map(quoteDao.getAll(), quotes -> {
            List<Quote> list = new ArrayList<>(quotes);
            Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(seed));
            return list;
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "New instance created...");
    }

    public LiveData<List<Quote>> getQuotes(){
        return quotes;
    }

    public void updateQuote(Quote quote, QuoteRepository.CallBackListener listener){
        Future<?> future = DB.databaseWriteExecutor.submit(() -> quoteDao.update(quote));

        futureCallback(future, listener);
    }

    private void futureCallback(Future<?> future, QuoteRepository.CallBackListener listener){
        try {
            future.get();
            if(future.isDone())
                listener.onSuccess();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public interface CallBackListener{
        void onSuccess();
    }
}
```

I've initialized `LiveData<List<Quote>> quotes` with `quoteDao.getAll()` and shuffled the result.
With this, when I try to update any `Quote` object it works perfectly fine.

But when I initialize `LiveData<List<Quote>> quotes` with `quoteDao.getPreferred()`, update does not work properly. Here's how I am using `getPreferred()`:

```
    public QuoteRepository(Application application){
        quoteDao = DB.getInstance(application).quoteDao();
        quotes = Transformations.map(quoteDao.getPreferred(), quotes -> {
            List<Quote> list = new ArrayList<>(quotes);
            Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(seed));
            return list;
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "New instance created...");
    }
```

**Expected behavior**
Use case: User can add/remove as **Bookmark** any `Quote` from `LiveData<List<Quote>> quotes`. `Quote` should be updated for both lists i.e. `quoteDao.getAll()` and `quoteDao.getPreferred()`.

**Current behavior**
It works fine for `quoteDao.getAll()`.
But when the user tries to bookmark any `Quote` from `quoteDao.getPreferred()` it behaves like this:

- On first update it adds `Quote` in bookmarks. (e.g. updates object at index 0)
- On second update it removes previously bookmarked `Quote` and replaces it with currently selected. (e.g. replaces object at index 0 with index 1)
- Sometimes it does not update at all, sometimes it reverses the update automatically.

**How am I managing bookmarks?**
I've a column in `quotes` table named `bookmark`, it stores **1** for true and **0** for false

**Current Flow:** Activity/Fragment > QuoteViewModel > QuoteRepository > QuoteDao

- Am I doing anything wrong?
- Do I need any additional code to manage `LiveData` result from `Join Query`?
- How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `Query`, *Primary Key Column* of all of my *Entities* is named as `id`.

The id of parent (Category) was being assigned to the child (Quote).

I've replaced this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM quotes " +
        "INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = quotes.category_id " +
        "WHERE categories.selected = 1")
LiveData<List<Quote>> getPreferred();
```

With this:

```
@Query("SELECT quotes.* FROM quotes " +
        "INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = quotes.category_id " +
        "WHERE categories.selected = 1")
LiveData<List<Quote>> getPreferred();
```